# If your Linux drive is an SSD or HDD

Tags: bash, shell-script, hard-disk, ssd

I'm here trying to figure out a way to get this small script working properly.

The `cat` command should give me either 1 or 0:

```
if [cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational = 0 ]; then
    echo "SSD"
else
    echo "HDD"
fi
```

I googled around and I found that `cat` command in someone's post.

I am trying to make this script print whether drive `sda` is an SSD or HDD. I can test if it works by just changing the value after the equal sign from 0 to 1 and it should read it the other way.

I also want it to just print "SSD or HDD", nothing else to be shown.

Comment: Dam typo, and you kind of can say that. It is more of a bigger job. This small script is a small part of a bigger one.
Trying to put together a big script that looks for the machines
IP (public and private)
Disk Space (Left and total) and if SSD or HDD.
Memory of machine. 
The Kernel version, OS (ubuntu or etc) and alot more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cat` command exits `0` on success, non-zero on failure. You don't want the exit code of `cat`; you want a value in a file. Use command substitution `$(...)`, which captures command output.

```
if [ "$(cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational)" = 0 ]; then
    echo "SSD"
else
    echo "HDD"
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if [ "$(cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational)" = 0 ]; then
    echo "SSD"
else
    echo "HDD"
fi
```

In Bash you can also do:

```
if [ "$(</sys/block/sda/queue/rotational)" = 0 ]; then
    echo "SSD"
else
    echo "HDD"
fi
```